# Automapper - Map fails after profile is added

Tags: configuration, automapper, profile, convention

I am using mapping by convention and have issues when adding profile to the configuration. Consider configuration below. I am using AutoFac to resolve profiles in CoreMapper and the profiles are correctly injected.

#### Mapping configuration

```
public CoreMapper(IEnumerable<Profile> profiles)
{
    MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
        cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        cfg.ForAllMaps((mapType, mapperExpression) =>
        {
            mapperExpression.PreserveReferences();
            mapperExpression.MaxDepth(10);
        });
        cfg.IgnoreUnmapped();
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
        cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? null : str);
    });
    Mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
}
```

IgnoreUnmapped is as follows:

```
private static void IgnoreUnmappedProps(TypeMap map, IMappingExpression expression)
{
    foreach(var propName in map.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        if (map.SourceType.GetProperty(propName) != null)
            expression.ForSourceMember(propName, opt => opt.Ignore());
        if (map.DestinationType.GetProperty(propName) != null)
            expression.ForMember(propName, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}

public static void IgnoreUnmapped(this IProfileExpression profile)
{
    profile.ForAllMaps(IgnoreUnmappedProps);
}
```

In my code I have a generic class implementation with the line like this:

```
mapper.Map<TPoco>(entity);
```

**Note**: mapper is an instance of CoreMapper from above.
where TPoco is POCO model defined like:

```
public class ModelPoco : IModel {
    // props
}
```

and entity is database entity model.

The mapping works fine. The result of *mapper.Map< TPoco>(entity)* is correct.

I then proceed and add a profile for a specific map **that is not at all related** to the *ModelPoco* being mapped before.

The profile being added:

```
public class  RepositoryLayerProfile : AutoMapper.Profile {
    public RepositoryLayerProfile() {
        CreateMap<SomeOtherEntity, ISomeOtherModelInterface>();
    }
}
```

#### Version: 6.2.2

#### Expected behavior

Mapping of ModelEntity to ModelPoco should happen normally.

#### Actual behavior

The mapping breaks with the message:
**Unable to cast object of type 'Proxy< IModel>' to type 'ModelPoco'.** on line *mapper.Map(entity);*

I am not sure why does it create Proxy class for IModel interface and then tries to cast to concrete implementation?
I explicitly set that I want to map *entity* to a concrete implementation.

If I remove CreateMap from the profile it works fine, but the first time I define CreateMap in the said profile, it breaks.
It seems to me like it forgets about the configuration for some reason even tho it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I did, it sets the destination type to _IModel_ rather than to _ModelPoco_ like I specified in the mapper.Map method. I have a hard time understanding why it does that.

Comment: The type map that matches specifies the destination type, not the Map call. The destination in the Map call is used to find the matching type map.

Comment: Execution plan does not provide any info on where it got the type map. It tells me that it converts _ModelEntity_ to _IModel_ and tries to cast it to _ModelPoco_. I do not have any explicit map and rules and I rely on the engine to figure out how it will map it to the destination type.

Comment: :) And that's exactly the problem. You're mixing dynamic maps with complex mapping. That will never really work. My advice is, either set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false globally or create a separate profile with CreateMissingTypeMaps false where you do the more complex mappings.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I'm curious why mixing dynamic and complex will never work. You have engine that can figure out how to map between two types and you ask for specific type, and you have to return that type(hence cast), wheter cast will succeed is testable in runtime, so in my opinon engine didn't do good job figuring out how to map. For me biggest problem here is consistency any map you add can break prevouisly working dynamic maps, so why allow combining them, if you set CreateMissingTypeMaps to true, CreateMap should throw

Comment: This has been discussed many times before. But the short answer is, because it's complicated. So it's not really a goal for us anymore.